# Why does the face recognition code give errors?

Tags: python, face-recognition

Im trying to run a face recognition code where the picture on the camera frame is compared to jpg pics on a filder and if theres a match then there's a message greeting else print unknown but i get a

> recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer() ^^^^^^^^
> 'AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

i have installed VS, SMAKE, DLIB, CV2 and face_recognition but still the error persists.

```
import cv2
import os
import face_recognition


for filename in os.listdir("Camera_Roll"): # Camera_Roll is the name of the directory`
    image_path = os.path.join("image_folder", filename)
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(image_path)`
    encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)[0]

    if "reference" in filename:
        reference_encoding = encoding
        break

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture a frame from the webcam
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Convert the frame to grayscale for face detection
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Detect faces in the grayscale frame
    faces = face_recognition.face_locations(gray)

    # Extract face encodings from the faces in the frame
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(frame, faces)

    # Compare each face encoding to the reference encoding
    for encoding in face_encodings:
        results = face_recognition.compare_faces([reference_encoding], encoding)

        # Print the result
        if results[0]:
            print("Hello, known person!")
        else:
            print("This person is unknown.")

    # Draw boxes around the faces in the frame
    for (top, right, bottom, left) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the frame
    cv2.imshow('Webcam', frame)

    # Exit the loop if the 'q' key is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The error you are encountering is because you are trying to use the createLBPHFaceRecognizer() function, which is not in your code. From the code you provided, it seems you are using the face_recognition library for face recognition tasks. You don't need the createLBPHFaceRecognizer() function at all.

Comment: i am not but i ran it as is...